# Angular - Automatically select option based on condition

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working on a table which consists of several fields, one of which is a dropdown with values ranging from 0% to 100%. This dropdown menu is connected to an ng-model called:

```
task.custom_fields
```

Task is the variable I get from my ng-repeat. Another field in my task object is called:

```
task.finished
```

Finished has a value of 0 or 1, as soon as this is 1, I want my dropdown menu to automatically select the value connected to 100%. If anyone knows if this can be done with any Angular syntax I would greatly appreciate it if you let me know.

My HTML code looks as follows:

```
<td md-cell>
    <md-select ng-model="task.custom_fields['96203']" placeholder="100%">
        <md-option value="0">0%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.1">10%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.2">20%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.3">30%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.4">40%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.5">50%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.6">60%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.7">70%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.8">80%</md-option>
        <md-option value="0.9">90%</md-option>
        <md-option value="1">100%</md-option>
    </md-select>
</td>
```

An attempt to make the question less vague, as commented as well:

What happens is, I obtain data from my database, it consists of 'Task' objects. Each task object has a field called 'finished', this field indicates whether a task is done or not. My custom field indicates the 'progress' of a task. Therefore as soon as I obtain my data, and finished is set to 1, I want the progress to be 'done', better said, 100%. The value of the 'finished' field does not change while on the view, it is set to 1 or 0 beforehand.

Comment: use `$watch` and update `task.custom_fields` when it changes to 1 in callback

Comment: @charlietfl If field is HTML input or when provides `ng-change` or something like that, t's easier and more readable to use `ng-change`.

Comment: @Pneumokok that also depends on how `task.finished` gets updated. It may not have an input and be calculated from other things. If it is from another input then yes, ng-change is viable solution

Comment: Use whatever event that sets the `finished` flag to also set the `ng-model` of the select to `1`. The question is vague what event sets the `finished` flag so it is hard to give a good answer.

Comment: @georgeawg I updated my question to try and make it less vague.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide [code people can use to reproduce the problem](https://plnkr.co/edit/aUFtS17biNbRUt7Wo52o?p=preview). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).